Refreshing access token automatically?
I'm building a dashboard using Next, Auth js and the Spotify API. I've implemented the OAuth flow and the user connects with the Spotify account correctly.
Spotify after the authentication process gives you an access token and a refresh token, because the access token expires after 1 hour.
You can use the refresh token to get another access token and I would like to do that automatically, but for some reasons it doesn't work.
This is what I did in auth.ts, basically I followed the documentation.
import NextAuth, { DefaultSession } from "next-auth";
import Spotify from "next-auth/providers/spotify";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session extends DefaultSession {
    access_token?: string;
    expires_at?: number;
    refresh_token?: string;
    error?: "RefreshAccessTokenError";
  }
}

declare module "@auth/core/jwt" {
  interface JWT {
    access_token: string;
    expires_at: number;
    refresh_token: string;
    error?: "RefreshAccessTokenError";
    user?: DefaultSession["user"];
  }
}

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Spotify({
      clientId: process.env.AUTH_SPOTIFY_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_SPOTIFY_SECRET,
      authorization: `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?scope=user-read-private user-read-email user-top-read user-read-recently-played user-library-read`,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
      const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user; // !! is used here to convert the potentially truthy/falsy value of auth?.user to a strict boolean representation
      const isOnDashboard = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/dashboard");
      if (isOnDashboard) {
        if (isLoggedIn) return true;
        return false; // redirect authenticated users to login page
      } else if (isLoggedIn) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", nextUrl));
      }
      return true;
    },

    async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
      if (account) {
        console.log("New authentication, creating new token");
        return {
          ...token,
          access_token: account.access_token,
          expires_at: Math.floor(
            Date.now() / 1000 + (account.expires_in || 3600)
          ),
          refresh_token: account.refresh_token,
          user,
        };
      } else if (Date.now() < token.expires_at * 1000) {
        console.log("token still valid, returning existing token");
        return token;
      } else {
        console.log("token expired, trying to refresh");
        if (!token.refresh_token) throw new Error("Missing refresh token");

        try {
          const response = await fetch(
            "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
            {
              headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
              body: new URLSearchParams({
                client_id: process.env.AUTH_SPOTIFY_ID!,
                client_secret: process.env.AUTH_SPOTIFY_SECRET!,
                grant_type: "refresh_token",
                refresh_token: token.refresh_token,
              }),
              method: "POST",
            }
          );

          const tokens = await response.json();
          if (!response.ok) throw tokens;

          console.log("token refreshed successfully, returning updated token");

          return {
            ...token,
            access_token: tokens.access_token,
            expires_at: Math.floor(
              Date.now() / 1000 + (tokens.expires_in || 3600)
            ),
            refresh_token: tokens.refresh_token || token.refresh_token,
          };
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error refreshing access token", error);
          return { ...token, error: "RefreshAccessTokenError" as const };
        }
      }
    },
    session({ session, token }) {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.id = token.id as string;
        session.access_token = token.access_token as string;
      }

      return session;
    },
  },
});

Right now when I'm logged in, after one hour, if I refresh the page it will give me a fetch error(I'm fetching some data to display in the main page of the dasboard). It happens because the access token was not refreshed correctly. If I refresh the error page again, then it will work and display the data correctly.
What I want to achieve is refreshing the token automatically, without having errors, so the user can stay on the main page as long as he wants and refresh the data whenever he wants.
This is how I'm getting the access token in the page and use it to fetch:
export default async function Page() {
  const session = await auth();

  if (!session?.user) return null;

  console.log("Session:", session); // Log the session object
  console.log("Access Token:", session.access_token); // Log the access token

  const accessToken = session.access_token ?? "";

Thank you!

for clarification:
Is there problem with gettig the new token or is there a problem accessing it in the fetch for the data?

Do you get the console.log("token refreshed successfully, returning updated token"),

or do you get console.error("Error refreshing access token", error);
?


Edit:
Then i suspect there is something off with the way you fetch the new token.
Docs say for fetching from node environment the SPOTIFY_ID and SPOTIFY_SECRET need to be included in the header:
const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Authorization:
            "Basic " +
            Buffer.from(
                process.env.SPOTIFY_ID +
                    ":" +
                    process.env.SPOTIFY_SECRET
            ).toString("base64"),
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
        refresh_token: token.refresh_token,
    }),
});


I'm getting Error refreshing access token { error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'Refresh token revoked' }

haha ok then the part i left out was the important one. I think its the way you fetch. see above for suggestion.

I modified it. Do I have to wait everytime one hour or can I force the token to expire somehow so I can debug?

you can just adjust the condition on which the token is refreshed e.g.
if (true) fetch or in your case just if (false) for the cases where the token is still valid

I'm getting these lol
Token expired, trying to refresh
Token refreshed successfully
Token refreshed successfully, returning updated token
Token expired, trying to refresh
Error refreshing access token { error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'Refresh token revoked' }
I don't know, I guess I'm not storing the refresh_token and use it correctly to request a new access_token. How can I show you the updated code? I'm new on Stack Overflow

i can't comment yet as my rep is too low. Newbie here too. I see in your code above that you have a doebled try catch block. one around the function call and on ein the called function. i would get rid of this first

Hi! Thanks for contributing to StackOverflow.
If you have questions about the original post you should ask them in comments section of the post. That will ensure that your replies are written with a full knowledge. Many times questions in the comments also help the OP improve the question and help the community with better content. So, everyone wins! ;-)

This is how I modified it, but I'm not sure if it's correct yet.
async function refreshAccessToken(token: any) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(
          `${process.env.AUTH_SPOTIFY_ID}:${process.env.AUTH_SPOTIFY_SECRET}`
        ).toString("base64")}`,
      },
      body: new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
        refresh_token: token.refresh_token,
      }),
      method: "POST",
    });
    const refreshedToken = await response.json();
    if (!response.ok) throw refreshedToken;

    console.log("Token refreshed successfully");

    return {
      ...token,
      access_token: refreshedToken.access_token,
      expires_at: Date.now() + refreshedToken.expires_in * 1000,
      refresh_token: refreshedToken.refresh_token || token.refresh_token,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error refreshing access token", error);
    throw new Error("RefreshAccessTokenError");
  }
}

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Spotify({
      clientId: process.env.AUTH_SPOTIFY_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_SPOTIFY_SECRET,
      authorization: `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?scope=user-read-private user-read-email user-top-read user-read-recently-played user-library-read`,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
      const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user; // !! is used here to convert the potentially truthy/falsy value of auth?.user to a strict boolean representation
      const isOnDashboard = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/dashboard");
      if (isOnDashboard) {
        if (isLoggedIn) return true;
        return false; // redirect authenticated users to login page
      } else if (isLoggedIn) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", nextUrl));
      }
      return true;
    },

    async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
      if (account) {
        console.log("New authentication, creating new token");
        return {
          ...token,
          access_token: account.access_token,
          expires_at: account.expires_at,
          refresh_token: account.refresh_token,
          user,
        };
      }

      if (token.expires_at && Date.now() < token.expires_at) {
        console.log("Token still valid, returning existing token");
        return token;
      }

      console.log("Token expired, trying to refresh");

      if (!token.refresh_token) {
        throw new Error("Missing refresh token");
      }

      try {
        const refreshedToken = await refreshAccessToken(token);
        console.log("Token refreshed successfully, returning updated token");
        return refreshedToken;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error refreshing access token", error);
        return { ...token, error: "RefreshAccessTokenError" as const };
      }
    },
    session({ session, token }) {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.id = token.id as string;
        session.access_token = token.access_token as string;
      }

      return session;
    },
  },
});

